# Find based on multiple search criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large data sheet that I want to search and place values using VBA.

The worksheet has to do with scheduling and I would like to pull an employees schedule from this spreadsheet - Name:"Database" (Sheet5):

[image]

to this sheet- Name:"Schedule Admin" (Sheet2)

[image]

I'm trying to get B9, Sheet2 to search and match the name(A9,Sheet2) in the database (Sheet5, Column B) and then match the date(B8, Sheet2) to the database(Sheet5, Column A). Once from there it will paste the opening value from the C column (Sheet5).

At first I thought about a formula, but I would like the user to edit that as I have a working Save to Database button.

I created a base for looping and it works perfectly.. Just need something easier so I don't have to write this code cell-by-cell

```
 Sub Load()
    Dim dtFrom As String
    Dim LoadDate As String
    Dim y As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vCont As Variant
    Dim iCont As Variant
    Dim Result As Variant
    dtFrom = Sheets("Schedule Admin").Range("A9").Value
    LoadDate = Sheets("Schedule Admin").Range("B8").Value
    With Sheets("Schedule Admin")
        For y = 27 To 9 Step -3
            vCont = .Cells(y, 1).Value
            If Not IsError(vCont) Then
                If vCont = dtFrom Then
                With Sheets("Database")
                    For i = 100 To 2 Step -1
                        iCont = .Cells(i, 1).Value
                        If Not IsError(iCont) Then
                            If iCont = LoadDate Then
                                If vCont = Sheet5.Range("B" & i).Value2 Then
                                Result = Sheet5.Range("C" & i).Value2
                                Sheet2.Range("B9").Value2 = Result
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                        Next
                        End With
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: start with the search box in the upper right hand corner of this page.  Type in excel VBA Find Multiple and you will get your answer

Comment: Your methods break your data. Unless the user edits the information on the database worksheet and Sheet2 is populated from that, the data on Sheet2 is useless.

Comment: @Jeeped I understand what you are trying to say to work out of the Database sheet. It's more of a visual editing for a week-by-week schedule. It has a code that deletes old saves and saves new ones. I created a base for searching and finding the dates.. That is now attached.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to work on x to get the proper hours calculated, but this will get the results you are looking for.

```
Sub DoIt()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim fr As Range    'range to filter
    Dim nRng As Range, Crng As Range, c As Range, Lrw As Long, r As Range, x

    Set ws = Sheets("Database")
    Set sh = Sheets("Schedule Admin")
    Set fr = sh.Range("A9")

    With ws
        .ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=fr
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set nRng = .Range("A3:A" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With

    With sh
        Set Crng = .Range("B8:H8")
        For Each c In Crng.Cells
            Set r = nRng.Find(what:=c.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not r Is Nothing Then
                x = ws.Range("D" & r.Row) - ws.Range("C" & r.Row)    'calculate hours
                c.Offset(1) = x
            Else: MsgBox "Not Found"
            End If
        Next c
    End With


End Sub
```